# Removing the need to call utf8_encode when using json_decode on data from mysql JSON column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been happily storing JSON in a text column encoded in latin1 and shuttling data in and out using json_decode/encode.

I converted the column to the newish json type so I can pull out individual keys in my document in my SELECT statements. When I do this any **json_decode** calls against the string representing the entire document fail with a `JSON_ERROR_UTF8: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`

From a post here I learned that this can be fixed by passing the string through the **utf8_encode** function.

That works fine, but I'm wondering whether there is a way to avoid making my php callers remember to call **utf8_encode**.  It seems needlessly brittle to me.